# How to track osgi bundle failure information in Geronimo3

Tags: osgi, geronimo

My team is using Geronimo 3 and osgi to develop applications. When our own osgi bundle or eba fails in Geronimo, I need to track the detailed failure information. Is there any API I can use to do this? Currently I could only do it by checking error stacktrace in geronimo log which is extremely not precise.

thanks,
Chandler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added such a command to Karaf 3. It is called bundle:diag and shows the failure information for all bundles including blueprint and spring dm failures. As soon as Karaf 3 is released and geronimo switches to it you can use this. You can already try a karaf 3 snapshhot to see how it works.

Comment: Christian, Can you share the code? I don't think I'll switchi karaf3 very soon

Comment: You can find the code in the karaf sources. https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/karaf/trunk/bundle/